# Find out what branches are merged into master via Github API?

Tags: github, github-api

On the Github website they list what branches have been merged into master. I would like to know how to list those branches through the Github API.

Answer (score 2):

Using octokit.rb I find all of the branches, then for each branch I compare it to 'dev' or 'master' whichever is the main branch. I see who is "ahead":

```
unmerged_branches = client.branches('blainesch/prettyArray').select do |branch|
  client.compare('blainesch/prettyArray', 'dev', branch[:name])[:ahead_by] > 0
end
```

To find all the branches it looks like:

`/repos/octokit/octokit.rb/branches`

To find the difference it'll look like:

`/repos/gvaughn/octokit/compare/dev...treeish`